# ServiceStacks' Autoquery - Searching in Nested Results

Tags: servicestack

I have a question relating to nested results using ServiceStack's Autoquery.

Specifically,

Firstly,
I have two classes. A Parent class with a referenced list of children, as shown below:

```
    [Alias("view_parent")]
    public class ParentView
    {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string ParentName {get;set;}
         [Reference]
         public List<ChildView> Children {get;set;}

    }

    [Alias("view_children")]
    public class ChildView
    {
        [References(typeof (ParentView))]
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ChildName {get;set;}
    }
```

Secondly, I have an Autoquery class as follows:

```
  [Route("/parents", "GET")]
    public class GetParents : QueryBase<ParentView>
    {
    }
```

**Given the above,**

Does AutoQuery support searching within the List of children from the ParentView?

e.g. the API query
 /parents?ChildName=Tom

does not seem filter the results. Does AutoQuery automatically support searching within a List?

Thanks & by the way ServiceStack is pretty awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoQuery doesn't include any child references as part of the query. You'll need to [explicitly Join tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#joining-tables) you want included in the executed query.

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm, as everything does in ServiceStack.